# Powerpoint forward and backward action buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, powerpoint

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me a clue on how to manipulate and control Powerpoint presentations which are embedded via an  iFrame link in your webpage using JavaScript ? Are there libraries available for this purpose as well, because I have been searching and couldn't find any. All I want for now is to get the back and forward functionalities and apply them on my own buttons to move back and forth. I would appreciate any help that comes for it.

Comment: Without knowing how the powerpoint is embedded, there isn't really a good answer to this question. Perhaps it would be easier to recreate it with a JavaScript system like [reveal.js](FACTUAL FEMINIST)?

Comment: The ppt file will be embedded through an iFrame link

Comment: If you do not own iFrame content (can't change it) than you can't do anything. If you can, use `window.postMessage` API for events in iFrame listening.